# dynamically adding and sorting check box in java GUI

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, checkbox, dynamic

I am now working on a Java GUI data visualization Project. The program should load a data file (20-300M), and paints curves according to the signals in the file. There are so many signals and in different data files and the occurrence of these signals are also different.

e.g. I have two data files, names file1, file2. In file1, there are 3 signals that i want to paint (A, B, C), in file 2, there are only 2 signals (A, B).

In file1, Signal A occurs 10 times, B occurs 5 times, C occurs 4 times. In file2, Signal B occurs 20 times and Signal A occurs 10 times. What i want to do is to generate check boxes (which are used to choose which Signal curve to Show on the Paint Panel) dynamically according to the signals, and sorting these check boxes according to their occurrences.

That means, if i load file1, then check box of A should be on top then check box of B, at last check box of C. If i load file2 then check box of B should be on top then check box of A.

Is that possible to do that?
I hope that my explanation makes sense. Thank you guys so much in advance!

Comment: What have you tried?  Each time you select/load a file, it should update the checkboxes accordingly

Comment: Sure, you can do it. Please create a short runnable example ([SSCCE](http://sscce.org)), so we can understand where you have a problem.

Comment: Thank you guys so much for the quick reply. I'll work on a short example of what i have tried so far then repost it :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is one example for dynamic layout of components

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.CardLayout;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JCheckBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingConstants;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.WindowConstants;

public class DynamicLayoutExample implements Runnable {

    private static final String[] NAMES_1 = {"One", "Two", "Three", "Four", "Five"};

    private static final String[] NAMES_2 = {"Two", "One", "Five", "Three"};

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new DynamicLayoutExample());
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        JFrame frm = new JFrame("Dynamic layout");
        final CardLayout card = new CardLayout();
        final JPanel layoutPanel = new JPanel(card);
        layoutPanel.add(createPanel(NAMES_1), "1");
        layoutPanel.add(createPanel(NAMES_2), "2");
        frm.add(layoutPanel);
        ActionListener l = new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                card.show(layoutPanel, e.getActionCommand());
            }
        };
        JButton btn = new JButton("Show NAMES_1");
        btn.setActionCommand("1");
        btn.addActionListener(l);
        JPanel buttonsPanel = new JPanel();
        buttonsPanel.add(btn);
        btn = new JButton("Show NAMES_2");
        btn.setActionCommand("2");
        btn.addActionListener(l);
        buttonsPanel.add(btn);
        frm.add(buttonsPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        frm.pack();
        frm.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frm.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frm.setVisible(true);
    }

    private JPanel createPanel(String[] array) {
        JPanel result = new JPanel(new GridLayout(array.length, 1));
        for (String s : array) {
            JCheckBox check = new JCheckBox(s);
            check.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.LEADING);
            result.add(check);
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```